# T-SQL Is there any feature to avoid ambiguous column names when adding new self join to existing query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, self-reference, ambiguity

Imagine we have a complicated multiline query from 2 tables

- A (pkA, a1, a2)
- B (pkB, fkA, b1, b2)

and we have a query which we have not added table prefix for columns:

```
select pkA, a1, a2, b1, bb2,....
from A 
inner join B on pkA = fkA
where a1 = 1 and a2 = 2
order by a1
```

Now we want to add self reference column fkSelfA to table A, and we then want to change the self reference join to query, the query should all change to:

```
select A.pkA, A.a1, A.a2, b1, bb2, SelfA.A1 as SelfA1
from A 
inner join B on pkA = fkA
left join A SelfA on SelfA.pkA = A.fkSelfA
where A.a1 = 1 and A.a2 = 2
order by A.a1
```

As we can see we have to change all the query and add "A." to everywhere we have used table A columns.

I'm wondering if there is or will be any feature that ignores column names of a table in joins so we can easily add the join without being worried about ambiguous column names foe example:

```
select pkA,a1,a2,b1,bb2,SelfA.A1 as SelfA1
from A inner join B ON pkA=fkA
LEFT JOIN Ignore A SelfA ON SelfA.pkA=A.fkSelfA
where a1=1 and a2=2
order by a1
```

Comment: Short answer: no. Longer answer: no, and that's a good thing if it encourages people to prefix their column names where they didn't before. Today's unambiguous column could be tomorrow's name clash when someone adds a column. The worst thing you can to do a database is make it not resilient to the addition of a new column, as that's the most basic thing you want to be forward compatible with. Your original query will break if `B` ever gets an `a2` column.

Comment: That's completely true but I am talking about modifying existing queries of old project without prefixes

Comment: If you are able/required to modify them, then take the time do so *properly*. Adding prefixes to a query that is not currently ambiguous is a simple and non-intrusive operation on a query that has no chance of breaking it. Tools like [SSDT](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt) with database projects have autocomplete and can help with this. If you are insistent on having no prefixes, you have to do ugly, ugly stuff like introduce views that explicitly rename columns.

Comment: Thank you Jeroen, I feel like you are the programmer responsible of adding features to T-SQL as you are so against adding features ;)
The suggested feature can solve many problems, not only my scenario

Comment: If you want to suggest a new feature, you can do so on [Connect](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server). You'll be happy to know I am not actually involved in the decision process of what features to consider...

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could do this:

```
SELECT pkA, a1, a2, b1, bb2, SelfA1
FROM A INNER JOIN B ON pkA=fkA
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT SelfA.A1 AS SelfA1
    FROM A SelfA
    WHERE SelfA.pkA=A.fkSelfA
) X
WHERE a1=1 AND a2=2
ORDER BY a1
```

However, it's better to prefix all columns with table aliases. To help you with that, you could use a tool like [Red Gate SQLPrompt](https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-prompt/).